# railsでcsvファイルを取り込む際に、トランザクションを使いたいです。(エラー発生時は全ての行の変更を取り消し、元の画面に戻ってエラー表示させる)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

railsでwebアプリケーションを作成しています。そこでcsvファイルの取り込み機能の実装を現在しています。csv取り込みはできたのですが、csvファイルを取り込む際に、トランザクションを使いたいです。(エラー発生時は全ての変更を取り消し、元の画面に戻ってエラー表示させたいです) しかし、いまいち実装方法がわからなかったため、質問させていただきました。

```
$ rails -v 
5.0.0
```

controller/costs_controller.rb

```
def import
  if params[:csv_file].blank?
    redirect_to action: 'index', error: '読み込むCSVを選択してください'
  elsif File.extname(params[:csv_file].original_filename) != ".csv"
    redirect_to action: 'index', notice: 'csvファイルのみ読み込み可能です'
  else
    num = Cost.import_by_csv(params[:csv_file])
    redirect_to action: 'index', notice: "#{ num.to_s }件のデータ情報を追加/更新しました"
  end
end
```

model/cost.rb

```
require 'csv'
class Cost < ActiveRecord::Base

  #csvファイルの内容をDBに登録する
  def self.import_by_csv(file)
    imported_num = 0
    open(file.path, 'r:cp932:utf-8', undef: :replace) do |f|
      csv = CSV.new(f, :headers => :first_row)
      caches = Cost.all.index_by(&:code)
      csv.each do |row|
        next if row.header_row?

  #CSVの行情報をHASHに変換
        table = Hash[[row.headers, row.fields].transpose]

  #登録済みデータ情報
  #登録されてなければ作成
        cost = caches[table['code']]

        if cost.nil?
           cost = new
        end
  #データ情報更新
        cost.attributes = table.slice(*table.except(:created_at, :updated_at).keys)

  #バリデーションokの場合は保存
        if cost.valid?
          cost.save!
          imported_num += 1
        end
      end
    end

  #更新件数を返す
    imported_num
  end
end
```

views/costs/index.html.slim

```
= form_tag import_costs_path, method: :post, multipart: true do
  = file_field_tag :csv_file
  = submit_tag 'CSV読み込み'
```

route.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :costs do
  post :import, on: :collection
end
```

現状のコードは以上になります。トランザクションに関して調べたところ、

```
Cost.transaction do 
  ------ コード -----
end
```

のようにトランザクションを実装するとあるのですが、どこのファイルにどのように記すのかがわかっていません....
大変お手数なのですが、ご教示頂けますと幸いです。。
何卒宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

トランザクションは、一貫性を確保したい一連の処理をまとめるものです。

この場合は `Cost` の更新処理に一貫性を持たせたいということだと思いますので、`Cost.transaction do` ～ `end` の中に `csv.each` ～ `end` の処理を入れてください。途中エラー (たとえばバリデーションの失敗など) があってロールバックしたい場合には `raise ActiveRecord::Rollback` とします。

なお、データベース側の制約によって失敗した場合は例外が発生しますので、適切に処理してください。

Comment: 回答いただきありがとうございます。指摘通りにtransactionブロック内に`csv.each` ~ `end`の処理を入れたところ、transactionが実行されるようになりました。まだまだ改良すべきところがあると感じますが、参考にしながら修正します。どうもありがとうございました!